# Adding content from one controller to another controller's index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller

My goal is for users to add individual games pulled from an API gem (https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb) to their personal library. I want users to be able to browse other people's libraries. I have the games showing up via search along with a show page for each game.

I am running into two problems: can't add games to a user's library and can't view other people's library.

Here is my games controller:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

#search for games
  def index
  @games = GiantBomb::Search.new().query(params[:query]).resources('game').limit(100).fetch
  end

#Shows data for individual games
  def show
  @game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(params[:id])
  end

#Adding and removing games to a user's library
  def library
    type = params[:type]
    @game = GiantBomb::Game

    if type == "add"
      current_user.library_additions << @game
      redirect_to user_library_path, notice: "Game was added to your library"

    elsif type == "remove"
      current_user.library_additions.delete(@game)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Game was removed from your library"
    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to game_path(@game), notice: "Looks like nothing happened. Try once more!"
    end
  end


private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:name, :search, :query)
  end
end
```

When I try to add a game to my library, I get "Game(#70231217467720) expected, got GiantBomb::Game which is an instance of Class(#70231150447440)". So my @game is incorrect but I am not sure what should be there instead.

Even if I could add the game to my library, I can't view other user's libraries. Here is my current controller.

```
class LibraryController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @library_games = User.library_additions
  end
end
```

I get 'undefined method library_additions' even though it is in the model. If I change User to current_user I can see the page, but that means users can only see their page and not others.

Here are my game, user, and library model:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
has_many :libraries
has_many :added_games, through: :libraries, source: :user
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :games
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :library_additions, through: :libraries, source: :game
end
```

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I made my library a join table for users and games but I am thinking I didn't do it correctly. Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_11_19_143536) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "search"
  end

  create_table "libraries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Am I missing a migration or do I need the rework the models and controllers?

[edit] Here are my routes, I am getting a pathing error when I try to add a game.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :games do
    member do
      put "add", to: "games#library"
      put "remove", to: "games#library"
    end
  end
  resources :library, only:[:index]
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/search', to: 'games#search', as: :search
  get '/games', to: 'games#index', as: :index
  get '/user/:id', to: 'user#show'
  get '/user/:id/library', to: 'library#index', as: :user_library
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the error clearly states it is expecting an instance of `Game` not `GiantBomb::Game`, so you have to create one.

```
@game = Game.new(name: 'some name', other fields ....)

if type == "add"
  current_user.library_additions << @game
```

About the other error you can only call association methods on an instance not on the class itself

```
def index
  # You could get the user'id through params for example
  @library_games = User.find(params[:user_id]).library_additions
end
```